# How to use pandas groupby on one column with agg - max one col, min another col - without producing multi-level columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max, aggregate

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

[image]

```
account_number = [1234, 5678, 9012, 1234.0, 5678, 9012, 1234.0, 5678, 9012, 1234.0, 5678, 9012]
client_name = ["Ford", "GM", "Honda", "Ford", "GM", "Honda", "Ford", "GM", "Honda", "Ford", "GM", "Honda"]
database = ["DB_Ford", "DB_GM", "DB_Honda", "DB_Ford", "DB_GM", "DB_Honda", "DB_Ford", "DB_GM", "DB_Honda", "DB_Ford", "DB_GM", "DB_Honda"]
server = ["L01SQL04", "L01SQL08", "L01SQL12", "L01SQL04", "L01SQL08", "L01SQL12", "L01SQL04", "L01SQL08", "L01SQL12", "L01SQL04", "L01SQL08", "L01SQL12"]
order_num = [2145479, 2145506, 2145534, 2145603, 2145658, 2429513, 2145489, 2145516, 2145544, 2145499, 2145526, 2145554]
customer_dob = ["1967-12-01", "1963-07-09", "1986-12-05", "1967-11-01", None, "1986-12-05", "1967-12-01", "1963-07-09", "1986-12-05", "1967-12-01", "1963-07-09", "1986-12-04"]
purchase_date = ["2022-06-18", "2022-04-11", "2021-01-18", "2022-06-20", "2022-04-11", "2021-01-18", "2022-06-22", "2022-04-13", "2021-01-18", "2022-06-24", "2022-04-18", "2021-01-18"]

d = {
    "account_number": account_number, 
    "client_name" : client_name,
    "database" : database,
    "server" : server,
    "order_num" : order_num,
    "customer_dob" : customer_dob,
    "purchase_date" : purchase_date,
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dates = ["customer_dob", "purchase_date"]
for date in dates:
    df[date] = pd.to_datetime(df[date])
```

The customer's date of birth (DOB) and purchase date (PD) should be the same per account_number, but since there can be a data entry error on either one, I want to perform a groupby on the account_number and get the max on the DOB, and the min on the PD.  This is easy to do if all I want are those two columns in addition to the account_number:

[image]

```
result = df.groupby("account_number").agg({"customer_dob": "max", "purchase_date": "min"}).reset_index()
result
```

However, I want the other columns as well, as they are guaranteed to be the same for each account_number.  The problem is, when I attempt to include the other columns, I get multi-level columns, which I don't want.  This first attempt not only produced multi-level columns, but I don't even see the actual values for DOB and PD

[image]

```
result = df.groupby("account_number")["client_name", "database", "server", "order_num"].agg({"customer_dob": "max", "purchase_date": "min"}).reset_index()
result
```

The second attempt included the DOB and PD, but now twice for each account number, while still producing multi-level columns:

[image]

```
result = df.groupby("account_number")["client_name", "database", "server", "order_num", "customer_dob", "purchase_date"].agg(
    {"patient_dob": "max", "insert_date": "min"}).reset_index()
result
```

I just want the end result to look like this:

[image]

So, that's my question to all you Python experts: what do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: order numbers are not unique. how do you choose order# 2145479 and dropped the others?

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Just for this example, feel free to leave order_num out.  They should have been the same in my example, and clearly, they are not.  The rest of the columns should be unique per account_number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leaving the order number out, per your comment above. If order # are same for an account, then add the order number to the columns list in merge

```
result = df.groupby("account_number").agg({"customer_dob": "max", "purchase_date": "min"}).reset_index()

result.merge(df[['account_number','client_name','database','server' ]]  ,
            how='left',
            on='account_number').drop_duplicates()
```

```
    account_number  customer_dob    purchase_date   client_name     database    server
0           1234.0    1967-12-01       2022-06-18   Ford            DB_Ford     L01SQL04
4           5678.0    1963-07-09       2022-04-11   GM              DB_GM       L01SQL08
8           9012.0    1986-12-05       2021-01-18   Honda           DB_Honda    L01SQL12
```

Comment: Perfect.  Your answer is exactly what I was looking for!  At least, I know now there is no permutation of groupby - by itself - that does the trick.  That is what was so frustrating about my earlier attempts to solve this problem.  Thanks so much, @Naveed!

Comment: Done.  I accepted your answer.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
agg(new_col_1=(col_1, 'sum'), new_col_2=(col_2, 'min'))
```